# como extraer de un string una parte de esa cadena en php

Tags: php

tengo una cadena  y quiero de ella extraer la parte donde esta "x-csrf-token: h42IQwpwl8lNJk1h-5h-gA==", como puedo hacer, cabe señalar que despues de x-csrf-token: ese token cambia.

"HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-language=ES&sap-client=200; path=/ set-cookie: MYSAPSSO2=AjQxMDMBABhQAEwAQQBNACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAACAAYyADAAMAADABBMAE0AUQAgACAAIAAgACAABAAYMgAwADIAMgAwADcAMgAwADEANwAyADEABQAEAAAACAYAAlgACQACUwD%2fA1YwggNSBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKgggNDMIIDPwIBATELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIICUzCCAk8wggIQAggKIBcDCAJVATAJBgcqhkjOOAQDMA4xDDAKBgNVBAMTA01DRDAeFw0xNzAzMDgwMjU1MDFaFw0zODAxMDEwMDAwMDFaMA4xDDAKBgNVBAMTA01DRDCCAbcwggErBgcqhkjOOAQBMIIBHgKBgQDR1QCqIhRZ5BBCYTjE1vg%2fAE3xpe2q3iJy7EqneezHVtSrnku4U8zZftxwDUyjbY0%2fgQPfmrVm%2frRsSuMOeMFYA%2188ecvUReTq5paFh7pEefyq%21aq89OVYJcIrtusgrf0nPnE9NKTBaMDYEyvydXHr8ncBS33kINEzSduj%2fcZnoQIVAO2rHAZGO77mkvQbu9qdCHdZQBjBAoGAZSp4ePbsFolmlYHZ8KOYp8NvTai9v0i8DbpDdyQ5%21zBWSNPYym7tAVKbRxduKX9Lz6%21EbiyDFQ0EIJTxw%21bJqP65Hh2sGbIN%21oZAn9Wh6AzECinM19jKwePe1wZ91JHvVDE0%2f0UIX6vCBKCvUUr4MvgCtR1RuQRD4n6pEKsnvE8DgYUAAoGBANBEHdGH2xAfe5OfA9hI6YK24fqBUUkZem8tBwrKJqb5ZC5NbtX47OeVkGqeuJcx%2f%21SY2ZXTH7Xdd9YmlLIxwyNj%2fMbKCxJuGRrmLVm5AZ3ZAgbM81YQ3KHWcvY2SF4rbTgSMphFm8mh%2fIsZYTdMQ3kvkm6K5U0Zf5B5QXGEm6kyMAkGByqGSM44BAMDLgAwKwITQhFjel55db%2fA7UD00x8mAaln7wIUbIL4kIO4phQkfgFSX0hZyXxxM%2foxgcgwgcUCAQEwGjAOMQwwCgYDVQQDEwNNQ0QCCAogFwMIAlUBMAkGBSsOAwIaBQCgXTAYBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEPFw0yMjA3MjAxNzIxMjRaMCMGCSqGSIb3DQEJBDEWBBQTrVAI5tlLMxvr5Ob%2fFBNw4oNmkzAJBgcqhkjOOAQDBC8wLQIUFis88X5E8KTrQrH4hWl0B351qT8CFQDAd4P3rhedkfBByrzds%2f5jr9BX0Q%3d%3d; path=/; domain=.lam.com.do set-cookie: SAP_SESSIONID_LMQ_200=_lRDoYjD7nYp6QGaJvK6rmFF1FcIUBHtgfdQa42TtUk%3d; path=/ content-type: application/xml;charset=utf-8 content-length: 1131 x-csrf-token: h42IQwpwl8lNJk1h-5h-gA== dataserviceversion: 1.0 sap-perf-fesrec: 235432.000000 " Numero de secuencia: 1000390"

Answer (score 1):

Primero ubicas el identificador del token con [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php). Luego, otra vez con `strpos()`, encuentras el siguiente espacio a partir del identificador anterior.
El token será lo que haya entre esos dos (2) delimitadores:

```
<?php
$str = "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented set-cookie: sap ..."; // Aquí la cadena larga
$needle = 'x-csrf-token: '; // Incluir el espacio
$pos_needle = strpos($str, $needle);
$token_start = $pos_needle + strlen($needle); // Empieza al final de $needle
$pos_next_space = strpos($str, ' ', $token_start); // pos del espacio al final del token
$token_offset = $pos_next_space - $token_start; // longitud del token
echo substr($str, $token_start, $token_offset);
```

Esto da como salida: `h42IQwpwl8lNJk1h-5h-gA==`. Y obvio, se lo puedes asignar a una variable.

Answer (score 1):

Parséalo como una cadena de consulta con [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str($tuCadena,$arreglo);
echo $arreglo['x-csrf-token'];
```